# Printing multiple lists in a list without brackets

Tags: python, list, join, printing

CODE1: It works, output is 123.

```
grid1=['1','2','3']
test=''.join(grid1)
print(test)
```

CODE2:  I modified it to this, and it fails, throwing the error message listed below.

```
grid2 = [
['1','2','3'],
['4','5','6']
]

test=''.join(grid2)
print(test)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/V/Desktop/0 Python/GridTEST.py", line 10, in <module>
    test=''.join(grid2)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

CODE3:  I did some digging and found a solution to my issue with the following.

```
for x in grid2:
    print (''.join(map(str, x)))
```

My questions are:

1. Why is CODE2 failing with the addition of another list?
2. Can someone breakdown for me what CODE3 is actually doing? (ie step by step)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know is that `separator.join(iterable)` requires `iterable` to be a sequence of **strings**. It then returns a new string, with all strings in `iterable` joined with string `separator`.

> Why is CODE2 failing with the addition of another list?

CODE2 fails, because `iterator` is a sequence of lists, not a sequence of strings.

> Can someone breakdown for me what CODE3 is actually doing? (ie step by step)

CODE3 is wrong the way you presented it. It should be:

```
for x in grid2:
    print (''.join(map(str, x)))
```

The loop iterates over the elements in `grid2`. Each element is a list of strings, right? `x` is the loop variable. So, in each iteration, `x` is a list of strings. `map(str, x)` applies the function `str()` to all elements in `x`, and returns a new list. CODE3 basically does what CODE1 is doing, just for each sub-list separately.

Comment: And then, eventually you can end up with: `print(*map(''.join, grid2),sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't `join` two lists as strings - you can only `join` strings.  What `code3` does, is extract string values from the inside lists that you iterate over.  The inside lists contains strings, the outside list contains lists - which is why you can't `join` them as strings.

```
for x in grid2:
    test = ''.join(x)
```

would also 'work' (except `test` would get overwritten second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

**CODE2** is failing with the addition of another list because when you do `sep.join(my_list)` it relies on each item in the `list` being an `str`. This is why it says `'sequence item 0'` referring to an item within your `list`, not the `list` itself. With this in mind, you cannot `join` two lists.

**CODE3** just turns all items in sequence `x` into strings to make a *new* `list` of strings that have been made from the items within.

You could also do this, instead of CODE3:

```
[''.join(l) for l in grid2]  # This is called a list comprehension.
```